# ngModel error issue in Angular. input property binding issue

Tags: angular, angular-directive

I am trying to bind a property using `ngModel` but it is giving error again and again. I have `convert` method defined in component which takes one `parameter`. I am not able to understand why it is giving issue.
html file code

```
<input type="text" [(ngModel)]="my_message" />
<button (onclick)="convert({'message':my_message})">Submit</button>
```

Component class code

```
import { Component, OnInit } from '@angular/core';
import { UppercaseConvertorService } from '../../services/uppercase-convertor.service';
import { HttpErrorResponse } from '@angular/common/http';
import { FormsModule } from '@angular/forms';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-uppercase-convertor',
  templateUrl: './uppercase-convertor.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./uppercase-convertor.component.css']
})
export class UppercaseConvertorComponent implements OnInit {
  public result: any;
  constructor(private _service: UppercaseConvertorService) { }

  ngOnInit() {
  }
  public convert(obj): any {
    this._service.convertToUpperCase(obj).subscribe(
      res => this.result = res,
      (err: HttpErrorResponse) => {
        console.error(err);

      }
    )
  }
}
```

Error:
[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to define `my_message` in component like below. The error says its not defined in the component. `ngModel` actually binds your component data variables to your html input UI controls

```
public result: any;
public my_message;
```

then in convert put it like this

```
public convert(): any {
  const obj = {'message': this.my_message}
    this._service.convertToUpperCase(obj).subscribe(
```

and in the html file change it to

```
<button (onclick)="convert()">Submit</button>
```

Comment: Was this helpful for you? Did it resolve your issue?